# Monitoring queue having old message

Tags: ibm-mq

We have a queue which needs to be monitored for message not being processed for a long time.
we set `QSVCINT(1800000)` that is 30 mins.

This event occurs only if there is no successful get operations or `MQPUT` calls have been detected within an interval greater than the limit specified. (30 minutes)

In our case queue is continuously getting message(MQPUT) in 30 minutes interval of time, so service interval high is not triggered.

Do we have any alternative to check the age of the message and get alerted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before answering the question, let's reset a slight misconception in the premise.  Queue Service Interval measures the time between a `PUT` to an empty queue or a `GET` that does not empty the queue *and the next `GET`*.  So the reason that you are not getting any event messages is not due to PUT activity but rather *to a lack of GET activity that would trigger an event*.  In other words, once the queue has depth, you will not get any `QSVCINTVL` events until a `GET` occurs.  Also, the events toggle between `OK` and `HIGH` so that once you get a `HIGH` you will not get another `HIGH` but should eventually see an `OK`.  Once you get the `OK` event you won't get another until a `HIGH` condition occurs as a result of a late `GET`.

So imagine that a program puts 10 messages on the queue and another reads the first message and then dies.  The `PUT` calls will not generate an event but will start the timer.  Since the now-non-empty queue defaults to an `OK` interval state, no event is enerated on the first `GET` which we stipulated occured immediately.  Since there were no subsequent `GET` calls, the timer continues to run but no event will be generated.  New messages can continue to arrive but the event will only trigger at this point on a `GET` call that occurs 30 or more minutes after the one successful `GET`.

If you were hoping to get a `QSVCINTVL(HIGH)` event base don no `GET` activity for more than 30 miniutes, it does not work that way.

Still with me?  Great!  Now on to the answer.

If you display the queue status (for example using the `DIS QS(QUEUE.NAME)` command) it provides the last `GET` time and date.  The `DIS QL(QUEUE.NAME) CURDEPTH` command provides the depth of the queue.  These two commands can be issued to runmqsc in scripts or directly to the command server using PCF commands and will allow you to directly inquire as to the time since the last successful `GET` on the queue, irrespective of any `GET` activity such as that required to drive events.

Using this method you can first validate that the queue has depth (because presumably we don't care if there are no `GET` calls on an empty queue) and then if so, see how long it's been since the last `GET` *even if the consuming program has died and there are no `GET` calls being made*.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks rob.. When a queue property QSVCIEV goes to NONE state QSVCIEV(NONE)? Is it the default value for property QSVCIEV?

Comment: Yes!  That property controls whether events will be generated.  If set to NONE then no event messages will be generated.  Also, based on this page http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.mq.csqzax.doc/mo10860_.htm I believe that you *can* get a HIGH event without a GET. It appears to say that an event can be generated for either a PUT or a GET.  Since an OK event requires a GET then I assume that a PUT which occurs after the QSVCINTVL will be sufficient to generate a HIGH event. I don't have time to test it right now but that's what I get from the docs.